# Find basis for orthogonal complements

Tags: linear-algebra

Given V = $\mathbb P_{2}$($\mathbb {R}$) with an inner product space defined by
           $\mathbb <p,q> = \int_{-1}^1 \! p(x)q(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$

Find a basis for $U^\perp$, where U = {rx | r $\mathbb \in$ $\mathbb{R}$}.

I know I can find a basis for U first. Not sure What can I do next?

Comment: Is $R$ a general ring or $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a finite dimensional vector space $V$ we have $ dim V = dim U + dimU^\perp $. $U$ is a 1-dimensional subspace since it is the span of the basis vector $x$. It is clear now that the basis for $U^\perp$ must be the other two basis vectors, that is $1$ and $x²$.

Note: $V = U ⊕ U^\perp$

Comment: Now that I am thinking about it, it seems like I am implying, that it becomes clear from the first sentence that I wrote. It just follows from the very simple fact that we already know that the basis vectors $1, x, x²$ are orthogonal(easy to check) and we have already $x$ describing $U$ , so we need only $x²$ and $1$ to describe $U^\perp$

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

If $W$ is a subspace of $V$, write a basis for $V$ whose first elements form a basis for $W$. In this case, you can use $\{x, 1, x^2\}$- the first element serves as a basis vector for $W$. Then use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthogonal basis for $V$. The second two elements will be a basis for $W^{\perp}$.

Method 2:

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual inner product, there is the relationship: $(Col(A))^{\perp} = Null(A^{T})$, where $A^T$ is the transpose. With a more general inner product $(x,y) = x^{T}Qy$, the formula is $(Col(A))^{\perp} = Null(A^{T}Q^{T})$. You can find $Q$ by picking any basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$ for $\mathbb{P}_2$ (say $1, x, x^2$) and then you have $Q_{ij} = (v_i,v_j)$. For example, $Q_{12} = (1,x) = \int_{-1}^1(1)(x)\,dx$.